# Reinstalling windows 8.1 via rufus

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, bootable-media

It took me hell amount of time to fix windows 8.1 activation issue and update problem which is the update client being stuck on 'checking for updates'.But I finally fixed them all, now I want to create bootable flash media for my windows 8.1 to install it on another computer via Rufus, but I'm wondering when I copy my windows onto flash disk and install it on new pc, will the installed updates of my windows be installed on new pc too? Or do I have to reoperate the entire procedure to fix said problems again?

Comment: "create bootable flash media for my windows 8.1" How exactly are you going to create the 8.1 media, you mean image the current installation?

Comment: ''image the current installation'' so this is what I'm asking. Is it possible to copy my windows entirely onto flash disk via bootable media? I mean when I create the bootable media and install the copied windows on another computer via Rufus, will that windows be the same with that of my current one?

Comment: You can but it will not activate on different hardware, OEM licenses are tied to the original hardware for life.

Comment: Activation isn't the real effort requiring issue. My current windows is up to date, will the new one be up to date as well?

Comment: @DoomIsAtHand - No;  If you install Windows 8.1 from the default ISO it will not be current.  If you downloaded the updates once already from Rufus, then you have all the packages, you would just point Rufus on the new machine to those packages. **DO NOT** try to create an installation media from your current machine.

Comment: So how can I have update packages installed on new machine when I install wındows on it? How can I avoid being obligated to install new updates on new machine?